# Why does Apache change request method and toward to the file path?

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I was moving a project to another host and before in my computer, is was nothing wrong with it.
Here's the thing:

Laravel entrance file was in ./public/index.php, and there's a folder was in the same parent folder ./public/article

Then I have some route like:

```
    Route::post('/article/banner', "ArticleController@getBanner");
    Route::post('/article/getOne', "ArticleController@getOneArticle");
    Route::post('/article/getArticle', "ArticleController@getArticle");
    Route::post('/article/saveBanner', "ArticleController@saveBanner");
```

so when I use post method access "/article/banner" and it rewrite it to "get" method and it shows 403 forbidden, but others start with "/article" routes are all fine.

Is anything wrong with it?

Here's my getBanner controller:

```
public function getBanner(Request $request)
    {
        $page = (int)$request->get('page') > 0 ? (int)$request->get('page') : 1;
        $limit = (int)$request->get('limit');
        $list = Db::table('banner')->whereNull('deleted_at')->orderBy('created_at')->paginate($limit, array('*'), 'page', $page);
        return response()->json(['code' => 200, 'msg' => 'succeed', 'data' => $list]);
    }
```

Comment: can we see your controller @getBanner method?

Comment: of course@SamEzedi